# Error in simple Network

Tags: tensorflow

What is wrong with this tensorflow code? I seem to be tardy to see the mistake. It doesn't converge. It stopps by 2.30.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 100]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100]))

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, 20]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([20]))

W3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([20, 10]))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W1), b1))
y2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(y1, W2), b2))
y3 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(y2, W3), b3))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y3), reduction_indices=[1]))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

for _ in range(10000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    print(sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys}))
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of things that should be addressed:

- The learning rate of 0.5 is quite large for stochastic gradient descent. If a network isn't training, you can always try with different values, typically in the range [1e-2, 1e-5].
- Networks initialized with zeros (`tf.zeros`) fail to learn for two reasons:

  1. Without any difference between parameter values, gradient is shared evenly across them all, meaning that they all learn to be the same value.
  2. As the gradients are multiplied by weights during back-propagation, the resultant value will always equal zero - meaning no change in weight values.

I would also recommend using the built-in `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` instead of doing it yourself. It's generally a good idea, as it minimizes the chance of making a mistake along the way. :)